# Specifying context with the jQuery interface for i18next

Tags: jquery, i18next

I want to use context on translations embedded in the page, however I can't seem to work out how to make it work without manually applying the translation with the context specified.
I've tried putting the context in `data-i18n-options` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50wnqrym/

Comment: As a side note, I couldn't get the code in the jsfiddle to do anything in the built in fiddle thing. Do I have to do anything special to get it to run the JS?